# I cannot merge two skeletal meshes together unfortunately

Tags: merge, skeletal-animation, skeletal-mesh

I have a pistol model from blender that is made up of two parts: the slide, and the rest of the gun so that it is easier to animate the slide. I exported the model with the working bone (slide) as an fbx and then imported just a static mesh to unreal, getting 2 static meshes because it was 2 objects in the blender file. I was able to merge the actors for the static mesh. However, when I go to import the skeletal mesh, I get all the skeletal assets and the meshes appear to be the same as the static mesh, however, when I try to merge the skeletal meshes, it is unable to do so, saying "insufficient mesh components found for merging". I have searched all over the internet and I haven't found anyone with a similar issue.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than merging, try and join them. They should be joinable if they are part of the same armature.

Answer (score 0):

The only time in Unreal you should be getting the error: "insufficient mesh components found for merging", would be if you were going into the Windows/Developer Tools/Merge Actors  But that is is NOT  for what you are trying to do!  I would ignore that,.  forever...  Use your existing tools like FBX and FBX settings,  Make use of the 'combine meshes' option,  and/or just make both part a CHILD of the first  BONE and the slide bone is a child of the same master bone, the slide mesh part is a child of the slide bone,.   It sounds like you are making avert simple thing complex,  the Merge Actors tool is not even for skeletal meshes at all,. This is an FBX, Blender and Importing issue...

Comment: Welcome to SO, please make proper use of text formatting, your answer is unreadable.